# SyntaxError on 'await' method call

Tags: python

I have been making a currency discord bot in python but i have been getting a Syntax error whenever I run this code.

```
users = await.get.mainbank.data()
```

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Does anyone know what to do to remove this error?

Comment: Share more of your code. if you are using async `await` should be separated. Ex.: `await called_func()`

Comment: `await` is a keyword and cannot used in the way you are trying do

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this is because the `await` Keyword is not valid to use as a variable, if that is what you are doing.
If you are trying to await a function, you would use `await whatToAwait()`. If you wanted to await the function `get.mainbank.data()`, you would use

```
await get.mainbank.data()
```

Though, I do not think this is what you want.

Comment: everybody refuses to give code, and then wonders why our solutions don't work.

Answer (score 0):

This question would normally be unanswerable(you provided no code),however, you gave us one line: `users = await.get.mainbank.data()`. I would recommend that you learn some more async stuff, however, the quick fix(assuming get.mainbank.data() is valid) is to change this to `users = await get.mainbank.data()`